# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre doble comilla y comillas simples? ( ' ' y " " )

Tags: javascript

Es que según yo se podían usar las dos para cualquier tipo de cosas como en strings en variables, ciclos, etc. Por ejemplo:

```
var comillasDobles = "Ejemplo";

var comillasSimples = 'Ejemplo dos';
```

Según yo esto era lo mismo, pero he visto en muchos lugares que a veces dicen "es que tu código esta mal porque usaste comillas dobles y deberían ser simples" y viceversa.
¿Alguien me podría explicar la diferencia? por favor.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Respuesta corta, no hay diferencia.

Respuesta larga, depende del uso que luego quieras darle a la cadena.

Si ésta debe contener dobles comillas, entonces tienes que usar comillas simples

```
 var dobles = 'contiene "dobles comillas" sin problemas';
```

y al revés

```
 var simples= "contiene 'simples comillas' sin problemas";
```

si tienes que contener ambas, entonces tienes que *escapar* con `\` una de ellas.

```
 var ambas = 'contiene "dobles comillas" y \'comillas simples\' sin problemas';
```

Probablemente quien te recomendó cambiar de comillas debía referirse a un caso en el que contenías esas comillas dentro de la cadena. En concreto, es un consejo típico para cuando se quiere incorporar html cuyos atributos vayan con dobles comillas (o al revés)

```
 var html = '<a href="#">';
```

o json, que obliga a usar comillas dobles

```
 var json = '{ "name":"value" }';
```

y también es habitual utilizar, al contrario, las dobles comillas cuando las cadenas contienen texto en inglés o en otros idiomas en los que se utilicen las comillas simples como apóstrofe, para evitar el fastidio de tener que utilizar todo el tiempo `\'` por lo que es mucho mejor empezar las definiciones con comillas dobles.

```
  var t1 = "That's an example";
```

en lugar de

```
  var t2 = 'That\'s another example';
```

---

Por último, para completar la respuesta, en la última versión de javascript (conocido como ES6 o ES2015 o ECMAScript 2015 o ECMA-262 6th Edition), existen las comillas inversas (o acento grave o backtick) `` ` `` que sirven para delimitar *template literals* pero que también sirven (abusando un poco de ellas) para declarar cadenas.

```
 var ambas = `contiene "dobles comillas" y 'comillas simples' sin problemas`;
```

Comment: Hola @Pa. , veo que han aceptado tu respuesta (que está genial!), para mejorarla creo que podrías añadir lo último que comento en mi respuesta del inglés (el I'm - I\'m). Un saludo!

Comment: hecho, gracias.

Answer (score 6):

La respuesta inicial es que en javascript, **no hay diferencia**.

Se pueden (y deben) utilizar **ambas* cuándo te encuentras en casos como estos:

```
var explicacion = "Esto es una explicacion y dentro hago 'referencia' a algo.";
var explicacion2 = 'Esto es una explicacion y dentro hago "referencia" a algo.';
```

Cómo ves cuándo quieres utilizar marcas **dentro** de un texto o definición que se abre por `'` o `"` se utiliza la *otra* dentro para diferenciar.

Asimismo podrías utilizar **sólo una de ellas**:

```
var explicacion = "Esto es una explicacion y dentro hago \"referencia\" a algo.";
```

Utilizando el slash `\` lo que haces es eliminar la sintaxis que tiene de abrir o cerrar quotation y simplement coges su valor cómo un char.

Otro caso en el que es más importante utilizar ambas es para que no haya problemas en tiempo de ejecución en **otros lenguajes** cómo `html`:

```
<input type="button" onclick="llamadaJavascript('hola')" />
```

Cómo ves es importante diferenciar entre la comilla simple y doble en ese caso aunque también se puede hacer:

```
<input type="button" onclick="llamadaJavascript(\"hola\")" />
```

Que es lo que he comentado antes del `\`.

Puntualmente cuándo en código `html` haces llamadas a `javascript` que contienen parámetros calculados (en un `grid` por ejemplo) es importante diferenciar bien las comillas simples de las dobles.

Otra cosa importante, des de mi punto de vista **personal** es utilziar en `javascript` siempre que puedas las **dobles comillas** cuándo defines strings ya que:

```
var ejemplo3 = "I'm giving you an example";
```

Si lo hacemos con comillas simples...

```
var ejemplo4 = 'I\'m giving you an example';
```

Tenemos que utilizar `\` ya que **ya estamos utilizando** la comilla simple en su definición y al ser la comilla simple un carácter típico en inglés es fastidioso tener que utilizar todo el rato `\'` por que es mucho mejor empezar las definiciones con comillas dobles.