# Correcta sintaxis de document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Revisando mi código, me di cuenta que tengo diferente la sintaxis del document.getelementbyid:

```
   document.getElementById("prcavance").value = value ;
    document.getElementById('up_file').disabled = true;
```

Lo tengo con doble comillas y otro con comillas simple, cual es la forma correcta?

Al parecer funciona de las dos formas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando lo que mis compañeros han comentado sobre que no hay diferencias entre comillas dobles y simples te explico lo siguiente:

> Lo recomendado es utilizar uno de los dos tipos de comillas y ser
>   recurrente en tu código con ello. En lo posible no utilizar ambos
>   tipos mezclados en javascript.

Por qué? porque generalmente no utilizarás javascript como único lenguaje hasta en casos como el de combinar angularjs + nodejs requiere de un tercer factor como HTML.

> Entonces si necesitas incrustar javascript en otro lenguaje (como PHP
>   por ejemplo) o viceversa te será muy dificil:
>
> Detectar que es un comentario y que no lo es  Observar rapidamente las
>   variables en el código a fin de depurarlo Determinar donde términa el
>   código de un lenguaje para comenzar el otro

En pocas palabras el mantenimiento del código resultará complejo, el código será un poco ilegible y además con gran probabilidad esté propenso a generar más errores al ejecutarlo.

Yo por ejemplo utilizo las comillas simples en lo posible para javascript y así dejo las dobles para HTML y PHP así cuando incruste javascript en mi HTML o PHP me sea más práctico y sencillo.

Un ejemplo didáctico es el siguiente:

```
<?php echo "<script>alert('Hola')</script>"; ?>
```

Como harías para ejecutar la instrucción anterior si ambas las colocas con comillas dobles? Sería un poco complicado.

Otro ejemplo:

```
var input = '<input type="text" name="prueba" id="prueba" >';
```

Notas lo sencillo que es incrustar HTML en javascript respetando el uso de comillas simples y dobles para cada uno de ellos?

**Observación:** Existen algunos casos donde usar javascript con comillas dobles es más factible que usarlo con comillas simples lo importante es intentar no mezclar ambas para el mismo lenguaje por lo comentado anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Da igual como lo hagas, JavaScript reconocera como una cadena de texto todo elemento que este dentro de "" ó '' 
Ya todo depende de ti y tu estilo de programación.

Particularmente utilizo las comillas dobles, ya que en otros lenguajes de programacion las comillas simples son solo para un caracter.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes una respuesta con la diferencia entre el uso de comillas simples y dobles: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/15374/87148

Comment: Las preguntas que son básicamente un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque los enlaces se rompen y dejan de funcionar. Además, es un enlace a una respuesta del propio sitio, lo más adecuado en ese caso sería dejar un comentario y, si tienes los puntos suficientes, votar como duplicado o reportar la pregunta para que sea revisada por otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.