# ¿Es posible crear un mailto con SweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert

Estoy haciendo una página web, y me gustaría añadir un mailto (enviar un email), a través de SweetAlert, pero me da error y me desactiva unos botones dinámicos que tengo. Alguien sabe si es posible hacerlo? Adjunto mi código por si me podéis ayudar. He estado comprobando, y solo me da error con el form en el JS. Si cambio  la etiqueta y pongo un título (h2, por ejemplo), no me da error.

¡Gracias de antemano!

JS:

```
$("#email").on("click", function (){
            swal({
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                title: '¡Enviame un correo!',
                html: "<form action="mailto:ejemplo@ejemplo.com?subject=Contacto%20pag%20Web" method="post" enctype="text/plain">Nombre:<br><input type="text" name="name"><br>E-mail:<br><input type="text" name="mail"><br>Commentarios:<br><input type="text" name="commentarios" size="50"><br><br><input type="submit" value="Send"></form>"
            })  
        })
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Botón contactame -->
            <button class="btn boton2" title="Enviar correo"><a href="#" id="email" class="estiloboton"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu error esta aqui en usar collinas doble en todo y no debe ser asi, debe hacer solo unas comillas dobles y adentro de ella debe haber comillas simples:

```html
"mailto:ejemplo@ejemplo.com?subject=Contacto%20pag%20Web" method="post" enctype="text/plain">Nombre:<br><input type="text" name="name"><br>E-mail:<br><input type="text" name="mail"><br>Commentarios:<br><input type="text" name="commentarios" size="50"><br><br><input type="submit" value="Send"></form>
```

te recomiendo leer esto:

[qué-diferencia-hay-entre-doble-comilla-y-comillas-simples-y](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15372/qu%C3%A9-diferencia-hay-entre-doble-comilla-y-comillas-simples-y)

y si quieres implementar un formulario de contacto con sweetalart puede mirar este gits github:

[gits ejemplo](https://gist.github.com/poszlo/8ca7032296a1f26b8ada)

una pregunta similar en stackoverflow en ingles :

[sweet-alert-with-form-js-3-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655649/sweet-alert-with-form-js-3-input)

igualmente puedes usar swal-forms para crear uno :

[swal-forms](https://github.com/taromero/swal-forms)
, mira uno en accion:

[demo](https://cdn.rawgit.com/taromero/swal-forms/master/live-demo/live-demo.html)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, no recordaba la diferencia entre las comillas.

Comment: denada  :) espero y te alla servido

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en que las dobles comillas dentro del atributo html al ser un string que tiene carácteres especiales deben ir con backslash o en su defecto cambiarlas por comilla simple.

```js
$("#email").on("click", function (){
            swal({
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                title: '¡Enviame un correo!',
                html: "<form action=\"mailto:ejemplo@ejemplo.com?subject=Contacto%20pag%20Web\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"text/plain\">Nombre:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"><br>E-mail:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"mail\"><br>Commentarios:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"commentarios\" size=\"50\"><br><br><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send\"></form>"
            })  
        })
```